# Interacting with a list of generically typed complex objects

Tags: c#, generics

I've been searching for awhile to see if anyone was trying to do something close to this and I find a bunch of people trying to interact with a generically typed List.  I instead need to interact with a List of complex objects who are generically typed.  Here's the current code.

```
public class RequestBundleItem<T> where T : BaseJsonResponseMessage
{
    public T Response { get; private set; }

    //intializers - code not needed

    public void SetResponse(String jsonResponse)
    {
        Response = (T)jsonResponse.JsonToObject<T>();
    }
}

public class RequestBundleManager
{
    private List<RequestBundleItem<T>> BundleItems;

    public async Task<List<RequestBundleItem<T>>> ProcessItemsAsync()
    {
        List<Task<JsonValueEventArgs>> tasks = //create tasks from bundleitems;

        for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Count(); i++)
        {
            Task<JsonValueEventArgs> curTask = tasks[i];
            var args = await curTask;

            BundleItems[i].SetResponse(args.ValueAsText);

        }

        return BundleItems;
    }

    public void AddItem<T>(RequestBundleItem<T> newItem) where T : BaseJsonResponseMessage
    {
        BundleItems.Add(newItem);
    }
}
```

This line is what's causing the problem

```
private List<RequestBundleItem<T>> BundleItems;
```

I don't know how to define this list since T is generic and just needs to implement BaseJsonResponseMessage but I don't want to type the RequestBundleManager itself.

SOLUTION:

I ended up removing the generic from the RequestBundleItem and the consumer is responsible for knowing the response type it needs back.

Comment: Why don't use `private List<RequestBundleItem<BaseJsonResponseMessage>> BundleItems;`

Comment: if I do that then the items no longer set their responses correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Make `RequestBundleManager` generic also:

```
public class RequestBundleManager<T>
```

And now you list can be defined with type `T`. Of course, you have to make sure that the `T` you use when creating your `RequestBundleManger` is the same as the one you used for `RequestBundleItem`, and you list will be homogeneous.

If you want your `RequestBundleManager` to handle lists with mixed `T`, then you will need to have `RequestBundleItem` derive from a base class or else have it implement an interface.

Comment: I don't want to type the manager because then it depends on a specific response type.  The manager needs be type independent since it is in fact just a manager.

Comment: @user2966972: I address that in my answer. Either define your list in terms of the base class or implement an interface. Your manager class needs to know *something* about the type of objects it's expected to hold.

Comment: I think what you are saying is RequestBundleItem : BundleBase or RequestBundleItem : IBundleItem.  If that is the case I don't see how that helps since the generic comes in when RequestBundleItem gets typed and not when the manager is getting its items to process.

Comment: @user2966972: You define your list as `List<BundleBase>` and all your methods will have to work with `BundleBase` instead of `RequestBundleItem<T>`. Generics aren't magic, the compiler needs to decide what they are at some point. You can't have a heterogenous list of `RequestBundleItem<T>` where `T` isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

Define the list in your `RequestBundleManager` like this:

```
private List<RequestBundleItem<BaseJsonResponseMessage>>
```

If you don't put a type on the `RequestBundleManager`, you don't know the specific type of the object inside the list except that it's a `BaseJsonResponseMessage`. Then it makes sense to just define it like that. It will give you access only to methods defined in `BaseJsonResponseMessage` though.

If that's not enough, consider defining an interface with all the methods you want to have access to in the `RequestBundleManager` and put it as a constraint on your type in `RequestBundleItem`. Something like this:

```
public class RequestBundleItem<T> where T : BaseJsonResponseMessage, IMyInterface
```

Then define the list in `RequestBundleManager` like:

```
private List<RequestBundleItem<IMyInterface>>
```